# CURL Разные ответы на один и тот же запрос, но сделанных с разных серверов

Tags: php, curl

Здравствуйте. Создал модуль для сайта на php, который передает нужную информацию в CRM систему с помощью CURL. Когда тестирую у себя на компьютере, то всё нормально - данные принимаются, обрабатываются и получаю ответ в json формате. Когда перенёс на сервер, то получаю ответ:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.12.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Запрос

```
      $query = array(
      'website' => 'http://' . $site,
      'name' => $name,
      'mobile' => $phone,
      'description' => $other_info,
      'ipaddress' => tents_extra_get_ip(),
.....
  );
 $url = 'https://crmte....';
 $http_build_query = http_build_query($query);

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$http_build_query);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
  $response = curl_exec ($ch);

  curl_close ($ch);
```

Я так понимаю, что это как-то связано с настройками сервера. Подскажите в чём проблема или как определить причину.

Проверил на втором сервере - всё нормально.

А может это быть связано с тем, что сайт, на который приходит ответ 301 на https ?

Добавил

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

в ответ  получил 403 ошибку You don't have permission to ... access on this server.
Админ сервера, где расположена ЦРМ, сказал что никаких ограничений у него не установлено.

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть код CURL...

Comment: @Alex Вариант сделать просто `GET` или `POST` запрос теми же параметрами, и посмотреть какой ответ выдает сервер.

Comment: Что это за хедер? и зачем ты задешь его? ` curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));`

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, это необходимо, чтобы cURL не высылал заголовок на ожидание

Comment: А посмотреть инфу по текущему запросу не вариант? [curl_getinfo](http://fi2.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-getinfo.php)

Answer (score 1):

Добавте строчку:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

И после этого Курл будет переходить по редиректам. Хотя, в идеале, разобраться с настройками этого вашего nginx/1.12.0, который прямым текстом говорит о своей ответственности за данное поведение.

Comment: добавил, и получил 403 ошибку You don't have permission to access 
on this server

Comment: Значит, как говорит сервер, вам туда нельзя.

Comment: так с другого сервера и с локалхоста всё нормально... а может быть это связано с размещением серверов?

Comment: Так другой сервер и настроен иначе, потому и разрешает вам. А ваш "проблемный" охраняется чем только можно, от кого можно и как только можно, потому к указанному ресурсу никто не может достучаться, в том числе и вы сами. Размещение серверов же совершенно непричем. Ну, в том плане, что проблемный конфиг может быть где угодно, но менять хостинг из-за дефолтного конфига - это как менять квартиру из-за того, что в ней стало слишком грязно.

Comment: Здесь не идет речь о смене хостинга - просто есть несколько разных сайтов, которые расположены на разных хостингах, но все они подключаются к одной црм. Так это проблема на сервере где сайт или где црм?

Comment: Там, куда идет подключение

Comment: админ срм говорит что никаких ограничений у них нет, что можно попросить его проверить?

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION должен решить проблему

Comment: Постарайтесь писать развёрнутые ответы, а не только полезные термины или ссылки.